# RegionTooBusyException when setting column family compression to GZ

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hadoop-yarn

I am creating a Hbase table with one column family with GZ compression on AWS emr instance with 1 master and 29 slaves using the below command

```
   create 'aaa_gz', {NAME=> 'd', COMPRESSION => 'gz'}, {NUMREGIONS => 28, SPLITALGO => 'HexStringSplit'}
```

when i try to import data into it from s3 using the below command

```
    /usr/bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.columns="HBASE_ROW_KEY, d:m, d:g, d:r, d:f, d:a" aaa_gz s3://bucket/prefix
```

i get flooded with RegionTooBusyExceptions and the MR job fails eventually

```
Error: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 188 actions: RegionTooBusyException: 188 times, 
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess$BatchErrors.makeException(AsyncProcess.java:247)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess$BatchErrors.access$1800(AsyncProcess.java:227)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.waitForAllPreviousOpsAndReset(AsyncProcess.java:1765)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.backgroundFlushCommits(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:240)
```

However when i remove the compression option everything works fine

i tried changing the hbase.regionserver.region.split.policy to ConstantSizeRegionSplitPolicy from IncreasingToUpperBoundRegionSplitPolicy and also the split algo to UniformSplit. i also tried increasing the numregions to a large number. but it did not help

I noticed that all the requests are going to a very few regions when the compression option is set to gz. compression works fine with the other three compression options (lzo, lz4 and snappy)

Please let me know what i should do to overcome this error

Comment: Did you try using other compression methods? As I understand gz compresses the best but it consumes a lot of cpu time, snappy is more balanced, consumed space/used time wise when you need to read compressed data often.

Comment: Yes, compression works fine with lzo, lz4 and snappy. its only with gzip i am facing this issue.